# AngularJS: fn is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After calling a function `results` I have an error: `TypeError: fn is not a function`. Before calling it, everything works fine, first `$http.get` gets good data. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
var app = angular.module("cowork", []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});

app.controller("SearchDeskCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.search = false;
  $scope.city;

  $http.get('/cowork/desks').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    return $scope.results = data;
})



$scope.results = function(search) {
  if (search){
    $http.get('/cowork/desks_city', {city: $scope.city}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        search=false;
        return data;
    })}    
  }

}])
```

**EDIT:**
My point in whole thing is to take results from first `$http.get` and then, after calling function, overwrite this data. Moreover, I need to pass one string parameter in second `$http.get` call (in function) to pass `city` parameter and then receive it in `request` (from Django side).

Comment: `$scope.results = data` can you see the problem? You are reassigning `results` to something else.

Comment: where do you call the results function?

Comment: `$http.get` 2nd parameter contains config setting not data like you passed here `$http.get('/cowork/desks_city', {city: $scope.city})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After getting a response from `$http.get('/cowork/desks')` ajax your `$scope.results` method is getting overridden with data

So while you are calling `$scope.results` method from it will throw because `$scope.results` no more available in controller scope context.

> TypeError: fn is not a function

Fix would be you need to rename results of `$http.get` to something else like `$scope.result` will be fine.

**Code**

```
$http.get('/cowork/desks').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.result = data;
})
```

Comment: Is there any way, that my function overwrites `results` data? Because that was my point.

Comment: there is way which i already explained in answer, you need to rename  `$scope.results` to `$scope.result`

Answer (score 1):

You are using results as a var in case 1 and as a function in case 2.

```
Case1: return $scope.results = data;

Case2: $scope.results = function(search) {
```

Use appropriate names.